# MySQL Query Optimisation - Single query restriction

Tags: mysql, sql

With my restricted access, I can run only a single query at a time. Quite often I have to run a query similar to the one below for tens of IDs. One by one it turns to be a pretty time-consuming task.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET columnA = X, 
       columnB = (SELECT max(columnC) FROM table2 WHERE id = <ID>) 
WHERE id = <ID>
```

Ideally I would like to use something like id in {id1, id2, ...}, however both instances of ID must be the same.

I am trying to modify the query so it can process number of ID in a single query.

==================================================

SOLUTION (quite simple actually):

```
UPDATE table1 
SET columnA = X, 
       columnB = (SELECT max(columnC) FROM table2 WHERE id = table1.id) 
WHERE id in (id1, id2, ...)
```

Comment: is there any relation in both tables?

Comment: Table1 and table2 have id column. id serve as primary key in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try this.

for T-SQL:

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.columnA = X, 
        a.columnB = max(b.columnC) 
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id IN ('ID','HERE',...)
```

**UPDATE**

for MySQL:

```
UPDATE  table1 a INNER JOIN 
                   (SELECT id, Max(columnC) As iMax
                    FROM   table12
                    GROUP  BY id) b ON a.id = b.id
SET     a.columnA = X, 
        a.columnB = b.iMax
WHERE a.id IN ('ID','HERE',...)
```

[REFERENCE](http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html)

Comment: I am getting 'Invalid use of group function'.

Answer (score 0):

Try belwo. Please do required changes because I have explained just way to do

```
 UPDATE table1 as t1 INNER
      JOIN (
            SELECT id
                 , Max(columnC) As maxval
            FROM   table12
            GROUP
                BY id
           ) As t2 ON t1.id= t2.id
    SET    columnA = t1.x
    FROM   columnB = t2.maxval
    WHERE id = <ID>
```